# Remove everything without Digits With Notepad ++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I wish to remove everything except Digits in my notepad ++ with regular expression.

can anyone help me with the String to use. that would help me get results like

```
from
416385-creativelive-photo-week-2014-hd-full-day-5.html
416668-creativelive-photo-week-2014-hd-full-day-4.html
421733-creativelive-photo-week-2014-day-2.html 

to 
416385
416668
421733
```

Comment: Aren't `2014`, `5`, `4`, and `2` "digits"?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? [Replace `(?m)^(\d+).*` with `\1` (or `$1`).](http://regex101.com/r/tM4dB9/1)

Comment: @Sam raises a good point. What about the numbers in the rest of the string? It sounds like the more appropriate question would be "How to drop everything upon finding a non-digit character"

Comment: also, if you only need the first 6 digits and drop everything else in each line then you could try replacing ^(.{6}).* with \1. (Do not forget to select Regular Expression as Search Mode before executing it.)

Comment: Your requirements don't match your expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this sentence:

> I wish to remove everything except Digits in my notepad ++ with regular expression.

do:

Find what: `\D+`
Replace with: :`Nothing`

It'll give : `416385201454166682014442173320142`, but I'm pretty that's not what you want.

---

Another proposal is to keep also line break:

Find what: `[^\d\r\n]+`
Replace with: :`Nothing`

It'll give:

```
41638520145
41666820144
42173320142
```

---

Finally, according to your example, I guess you want:

Find what: `^(\d+).*$`
Replace with: `$1`

NB.: Don't check `dot matches new line`.

It'll give:

```
416385
416668
421733
```

Comment: this part Helped.

Find what: ^(\d+).*$
Replace with: $1

NB.: Don't check dot matches new line.

It'll give:

416385
416668
421733