# Notepad++ remove non alpanumeric characters

Tags: regex, notepad++

What is the best way to remove non alphanumeric characters from a text file using notepad++?

I only want to keep numbers and letters, Is there a built in feature to help or should I go the regex route?

I am trying to use this to keep them as well as spaces `[a-zA-Z0-9 ]`. It is working but I need to do the opposite!

Comment: I would just go for regex, there are some good examples here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26411498/remove-everything-without-digits-with-notepad and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17274611/notepad-keep-numbers-only

Comment: I am trying to use this to keep them as well as spaces [a-zA-Z0-9 ]. It is working but I need to do the opposite!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In a *Replace* dialog window (<kbd>Ctrl+H</kbd>), use a negated character class in the *Find What* field:

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]+
```

Here, `[^` starts a negated character class that matches any character other than the one that belongs to the character set(s)/range(s) defined in it. So, the whole matches 1 or more chars other than ASCII letters, digits, and  any whitespace.

Or, to make the expression Unicode-aware,

```
[^[:alnum:][:space:]]+
```

Here, `[:alnum:]` matches all alphanumeric chars and `[:space:]` matches all whitespace.

[image]

Comment: How can I get it to ignore new lines?

Comment: Just use `\s` or `[:space:]` inside the negated character class.

Comment: Thank you, that is perfect and well explained